# recursive Function, to find even or odd digits inside given number

Tags: c, function, recursion

Basically, its printing only one instance when it happens, and i don't understand why, maybe has something to do with the code reseting every time and starting the variable at 0 again, and i got another question if someone can help me with, i have to return both values when its odd and even, like how many digits are even and odd at the same time, i'm having a little trouble figuring out how to do it

```
#include <stdio.h>

int digits(int n) 
// function that checks if the given value is odd or even, and then add 
// + 1 if it's even, or odd, it's supposed to return the value of the quantity 
// of digits of the number given by the main function
{
    int r;
    int odd  = 0;
    int even = 0;

    r = n % 10;
    if (r % 2 == 0) // check if given number is even
    {
        even = even + 1;
    }
    if (r % 2 != 0) // check if its odd
    {
        odd = odd + 1;
    }

    if (n != 0) {
        digits(n / 10); // supposed to reset function if n!=0 dividing
                // it by 10
    }
    if (n == 0) { return odd; }
}

int
main() // main function that sends a number to the recursive function
{
    int n;
    printf("type number in:\n ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    printf("%d\n", digits(n));
}
```

Comment: Please use 4 spaces for indentation of code

Comment: To me it's unclear what you want the function to do.

Comment: You need to use the return value from recursive calls for "something". Your current code just ignores the return value which is a problem.

Comment: its a recursive function, that does that, basically

Comment: ok... but your current code only attempts to return `odd`

Comment: yeah, because i tried only with odd, so i can see if i can return one value

Comment: in the end, it returns only 1

Comment: Your function doesn't always return a value — that's bad.  A function can only return one value; you seem to need two values returned.  You've got some rethinking to do.  One way to return multiple values is to return a structure.  Another is to pass pointers to the function.

Comment: i think, that my problem is that, the function it self keeps getting the value 0 back from start

Comment: You can return only one value from a function. In that case you may concatenate your two values as string conversion. And it's not clear based on what you decorated your function.

Comment: because at the start of the function, odd is defined by 0, thats what i'm trying to get around

Comment: Use the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger and compile your program with [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`

Comment: In the line `int digits(int n) // function` why don't you try to explain what the function does, rather than saying "it's a function"? It returns one int. So what does that stand for? If you want to return more than one int, either return a structure, or use parameters by reference.

Comment: edited it ......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`odd` and `even` variables are local in your code, so they are initialized by zero every time.
I think they should be declared at caller of the recursive function, or be declared as global variables.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void digits(int n, int *even, int *odd)//function
{
  int r;
  r = n % 10;
  if (r % 2 == 0)//check if given number is even
  {
    *even = *even + 1;
  }
  else //otherwise, its odd
  {
    *odd = *odd + 1;
  }

  n /= 10;
  if (n != 0)
  {
    digits(n, even, odd);//supposed to reset function if n!=0 dividing it by 10
  }
}

int main()
{
  int n, even = 0, odd = 0;
  printf("type number in:\n ");
  scanf("%d", &n);

  digits(n, &even, &odd);

  printf("even: %d\n", even);
  printf("odd: %d\n", odd);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: oh i see, you pass the value for the main function everytime, i never would have thought of that, thanks

Comment: i can't top up(cuz i'm new on this kinda of thing, but you have my eternal gratitude), it's a very good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing a function that counts the number of odd and even digits in a number, **is not to be done using recursive**. That is simply a wrong design choice.

But I assume that it's part of your assignment to use recursion so ... okay.

You want a function that can return two values. Well, in C you can't!! C only allows one return value. So you need another approach. The typical solution is to pass pointers to variables where the result is to be stored.

Here is the code:

```
void count_odd_even(const int n, int *even, int *odd)
{
    if (n == 0) return;

    if (((n % 10) % 2) == 1)
    {
        *odd += 1;
    }
    else
    {
        *even += 1;
    }
    count_odd_even(n/10, even, odd);
}
```

And call it like

```
int odd = 0;
int even = 0;
count_odd_even(1234567, &even, &odd);
```

Comment: Won't we can return an array technically is return 2 values?

Comment: @justANewbie No. To be strict, C can't return arrays! What you return in case of arrays is also just a single value, i.e. a pointer. That pointer may pointer to memory where you have stored several integers but - still - there is only one value returned, i.e. the pointer.

Comment: @justANewbie and BTW: In C can also not pass an array into a function. What you pass is again a pointer. Not the array.

Comment: @justANewbie Another "workaround" in C is to use `struct`. You can only return (and pass) a **single** struct but that struct may contain several values. However, in most cases that's not the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I found the problem you are facing. You you initialized you odd and even variable as zero. every time you call the function it redeclares their value to zero again. You can use pointer caller or use those as your global variable so that every time they don't repeat their initial values again.

Comment: that's what i was saying, at the start, but thank you man, someone already answered my question